# Android decode and save audio stream returned from intent

Tags: android, audio, android-intent, bitmap, decoding

I would like the user to be able to import custom sounds in my app to change the default sounds. I already have this functionality working for bitmaps, but I would like to extend to sounds as well. The crucial step I am missing is audio decoding. I do not know what format the sound will come in, so I need to decode the audio before saving it to internal storage. For bitmaps this was accomplished by the bitmapfactory and the bitmap object, but I cannot find an analogous service for audio. This is the code that I have so far. The bitmap portions work, but the audio parts are incomplete.:

```
private void retrievepicture() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);//retrieve picture has a code of 1
}

private void retrievesound() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("audio/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 2);//retrieve sound has a code of 2
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    usingintents = false;
    if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        try {
              InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getData());
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            stream.close();
            File deletefile = new File(savepath);
            System.out.println(String.format("Replacing file %s",deletefile.getPath()));
            deletefile.delete();
            saveImageToInternalStorage(bitmap,savepath);
            bitmap.recycle();
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    if (requestCode == 2 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
    {
        //The code for saving audio would go here
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    data.getData());
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

public boolean saveImageToInternalStorage(Bitmap image, String filepath) {

    try {
    // Use the compress method on the Bitmap object to write image to
    // the OutputStream
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filepath);
    // Writing the bitmap to the output stream
   if(image.getWidth() >480 || image.getHeight() > 480)
        image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, 480, 480, false);
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();

    return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return false;

    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by getting the file path from the intent, and copying the file as it is instead of decoding it. All the files that I looked at did not have a clear format(they weren't .wav or .mp3, there was no file type listed)

This is what my code looks like inside the onActivityResult for the sound portion

```
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
String FilePath = data.getData().getPath();
File original = new File(FilePath);

File deletefile = new File(savepath);
String newpath = deletefile.getParent() + "/" +  original.getName();
deletefile.delete();

File newfile = new File(newpath);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);

int read = 0;
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

while ((read = stream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
    out.write(bytes, 0, read);
}

out.close();
stream.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin 1.2**

```
    fun saveAudio(myAudio:Intent?):String {//TURN ON PERSMISSIONS ON THE EMULATOR IN SETTINGS
    //var bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    val audioURI = myAudio!!.data


    try {
        val audioDirectory = File(
                (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()).toString() + AUDIO_DIRECTORY)

        val out = File(audioDirectory, ("fullAudio" + ".mp3"))

        if (!audioDirectory.exists()){
            audioDirectory.mkdirs()
        }

        out.createNewFile()//cressh

        val file = File(audioURI.path)


        val fo = FileOutputStream(out)
        //val input = FileInputStream(f)

        var stream = contentResolver.openInputStream(audioURI)
        var read = 0



        fo.write(stream.readBytes(1024))


        MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,
                arrayOf(file.getPath()),
                arrayOf("audio/mpeg"),null)

        fo.close()
        return file.absolutePath

    }catch (e1: IOException){
        e1.printStackTrace()
    }
    return ""
}
```